# Send bulk mail using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Was working on a project which will be sending bulk mail to different people if the conditions are met.

Conditions :

1. Column U contains the final status (Open or WIP) (will not send if Closed no matter if current date is larger)
2. Column Q contains Closure date. Which when compared to current date, if less then automatic shooting mails to people.

I had tried to do with for loop but its giving shooting 4 mails with same To and CC. And not going to the next row to compare.

Thank you in advance.

Code as below:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim StrBody As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim arr1 As Variant

Dim i As Long, r As Long

On Error Resume Next
arr1 = Worksheets("Data").Range("Q2:Q" & Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Value
i = 1
For Each x In arr1
    For r = 1 To 2

        If x < Now() Then


        If Sheets("Data").Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "U").Value = "Open" Then   


            Set rng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            'Only the visible cells in the selection
            Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            'You can also use a fixed range if you want
            Set rng = Sheets("Checklist").Range("A2:B25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0


            With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            End With

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail


            If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "C").Value = "Operation_Support" And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "E").Value = "Quality_Assurance" Then


     StrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & _


    .To = "a"

    .CC = "b"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display
    '.Send

    ElseIf Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "C").Value = "Operation_Support" And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "E").Value = "Analytics" Then

StrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & _
          "PFB the process details which requires your attention." & "<br>" & _
          "The review for this process has crossed over due." & "<br>" & _
          "Please ask the process owner to review the Process Manuals and Maps." & "<br><br><br>"

    .To = "c"

    .CC = "d"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Process Manual and Maps Review is Overdue"
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display
    '.Send
End If

    End With

    i = i + 1
    Exit For

    End If
End If

Next r

On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Next x
End Sub
```

[image: First the code will run to compare 3-Jun-16 date and Closed(Final Status) then next it will run to compare 16-May-2016 and Closed(Final Status)]

Comment: There is no loop in this code - why would you expect it to move to another row?

Comment: @MacroMan I removed the for loop and then pasted.

Comment: Well we can't hep with code that we can't see now can we.... on another note, you're just ignoring errors in your code rather than actually dealing with them which also makes it impossible to help with.

Comment: @MacroMan Added the code. Now request you to help me. Thank you

Comment: @MacroMan Hi, I request you to help me with this. Your help will mean a lot to me. Thank you.

Comment: I will respectfully decline your request - you have added the code back in but I have seen no proof that you have actually tried to get that code working before asking someone else to 'fix' it for you. There are also many other issues such as the repeated use of `On Error Resume Next` that make code like this difficult to debug. Maybe someone else will have a go at it though.

Comment: @MacroMan cool. Thanks. Really thought you would help. N please dont say that I didnt try. You may not know.. Thanks once again for ur help.

Comment: I never said you didn't try, I said "I have seen no proof". You use `For i = 1 To 4` but then don't actually use `i` inside your loop to control the row. This suggests that actually the problem is caused by you not understanding how a loop works. Something that is widely covered on the Internet with detailed examples and not something that would be answered on Stack Overflow as it's too broad.

Comment: @MacroMan I apologize for this.. It was my mistake. I will try to work this out. Thank you for guiding. Cheers!

Comment: @MacroMan Sorry to bother you again... I made some changes in the code. Now its giving me error on `Next x` of `runtime error 92`... If now you could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: This will solve the problem above.

```
Sub Data_RoundedRectangle1_Click()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range

For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

If Cells(i, 21).Value = "Open" And Cells(i, 17).Value <= Now() Then

Set rng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            'Only the visible cells in the selection
            Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            'You can also use a fixed range if you want
            Set rng = Sheets("Data").Range("C1:V5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0


            With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            End With



Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail


    If Cells(i, 3).Value = "Operation_Support" And Cells(i, 5).Value = "Quality_Assurance" Then


        StrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & _
          "PFB the process details which requires your attention." & "<br>" & _
          "The review for this process has crossed overdue." & "<br>" & _
          "Please ask the process owner to review the Process Manuals and Maps." & "<br><br><br>"

    .To = "a"
    .CC = "b"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display
    '.Send

    ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = "Operation_Support" And Cells(i, 5).Value = "Analytics" Then

StrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & _
          "PFB the process details which requires your attention." & "<br>" & _
          "The review for this process has crossed over due." & "<br>" & _
          "Please ask the process owner to review the Process Manuals and Maps." & "<br><br><br>"

    .To = "c"
    .CC = "s"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display
    '.Send

End If
End With


On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End If
Next i

End Sub
```